# Join to Fetch data from two tables

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, join, android-sqlite

*Table* - **ecare**

```
name          h_id

Sam            1  

Deb            1

Kim            1
```

*Table* - **pweb**

```
h_id          sent
 1               1
 1               0
 1               0
```

Please `Check` [OUTPUT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348aa/2) in **SQL Fiddle**

I am using following *query* to fetch data from **ecare** those status in **pweb** table where `sent is 0` only

```
SELECT distinct e.name, e.h_id 
from ecare e 
INNER JOIN pweb p 
ON e.h_id = p.h_id AND p.sent = 0
```

But, I am getting **all three records** those available in *ecare* table, not only those where *sent = 0*

**Note:** I tried same *query* with **INNER JOIN** too, but *getting* all `three records` available in **ecare** table for that particular *h_id*

Actually, In my application, I am managing *status* of record (`synced` to server or `not` - if **synced** then I am showing *1* else *0*) in `pweb` table

But now, I got the requirement, where I just need to *show records* those are `not uploaded` to *server* yet, I mean those `sent` status is **0** in pweb....

Comment: Are you certain that you are getting all 3 records?  You shouldn't be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I am getting all 3 records

Comment: Try to use **INNER JOIN** instead of **LEFT JOIN**

Comment: @Sadikhasan No, this should not make any difference as each table has three records which all match.

Comment: @Sadikhasan already tried getting same output, all three records

Comment: Can you give **SQL Fiddle** ?

Comment: can you check `LEFT JOIN pweb p ON p.h_id=e.h_id`. Not sure if it will make any difference.

Comment: @MilanGupta already checked, getting all three records

Comment: is the datatype of h_id, same in both the tables?

Comment: Yes. INTEGER @MilanGupta

Comment: Give your table structure and data with screen shot.

Comment: Why datatype of "sent" is "Text" when only 0 and 1 are the possible values. That can be the reason of your problem. Try changing datatype of "sent" to "int". With the same datatype i.e "Text", you should try `WHERE sent LIKE "0" `

Comment: @MilanGupta now I can't make any change in our database, old developer did that mistake, now I just  have to get it done any how

Comment: @MilanGupta please check I have updated records for both the tables, I did mistake... actually this is what actually tables looks like

Comment: @Sadikhasan please check I have updated records for both the tables, I did mistake... actually this is what actually tables looks like

Comment: @Oreo it's working.. problem is not with your query. It's with your data. [Chek it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6020b/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT e.name, e.h_id from ecare e INNER JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE p.sent = '0' ";
```

replace hid into h_id

Comment: that's not the solution... I just did typo mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba4c7a/1

```
SELECT e.name, e.h_id 
FROM ecare e 
INNER JOIN pweb p 
ON e.h_id=p.h_id AND p.sent = 0
```

by the way your variant of query works as well

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba4c7a/2

```
SELECT e.name, e.h_id 
FRM ecare e 
INNER JOIN pweb p 
ON e.h_id=p.h_id
WHERE p.sent = 0
```

Comment: sqlfiddle please? or full fragment of your code, and some proof of how you get your 3 rows. according to sqlfiddle there are just 2 rows

Comment: probaly you query wrong database. so provide proof that you have same data in database: `SELECT * FROM pweb` what is output? post it here

Comment: yes, I checked that... but at my end, this is not resolving my issue, actually sent format is TEXT ....... help me buddy

Comment: I stop to help, because there is nothing to help, but debug. the case is not reproducible on fiddle, so that is not sql issue. that is your data or your environment  issue. and stop telling me the you did test, provide visible proof.

Comment: Alex bro please check I have updated records for both the tables, I did mistake... actually this is what  actually tables looks like

Comment: So - fix your data! or explain what is your expectetion and why? query works just fine.

Comment: I used SQL Fiddle, getting all three records, not only those where status is sent = 0 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348aa/2 and please tell me what I have missed

Comment: you missed you requirements. query SHOULD return 3 rows according to your query, if you need other result - explain why?

Comment: In my application I am managing status of record (synced to web server or not - if synced then I am showing 1 else 0) in pweb table, so now I got the requirement, where I just need to show records those are not uploaded to server yet, I mean those sent status is 0 in pweb.... that's why I need to fetch record those not  sent to server yet

Comment: Ok  so what would you recommend me ? I have created another column say id, and  it is unique in ecare and pweb table, now is there any way to get my target... see this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1243d2/1

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your query. It's perfectly fine.

Problem lies with your data. You have added 3 records in pweb table with same h_i **"1"** so your query will obviously fetch all 3 records.

You can verify in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6020b/2/0)

Comment: Yeah I agree, but anyhow, I need to make it possible, please check this one : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348aa/2

Comment: It' like one preson has test result as pas as well as fail....And you wanna show the person who has failed. It's not possible... If you wanna achieve it, you will reqyure to cahneg your tables accordingly

Comment: Ok  so what would you recommend me ? I have created another column say id, and  it is unique in ecare and pweb table, now is there any way to get my target... see this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1243d2/1